# How is 'The Homeworld' played correctly?

Tags: smash-up

In a recent Smash Up match we had the base 'The Homeworld', that has the following ability:

> After each time a minion is played here, its owner may play an extra minion of power 2 or less.

I played wizards (and something else that doesn't matter, because I had at this point mostly Wizard cards in the hand). I had a lot of creatures, because of a previous Portal and they were mostly Enchantress and Neophyte. We concluded I can them all play on The Homeworld, as they all have a power of two and playing one triggers the ability and allows me to play the next until my hand is emptied (or I decide to stop). Was that played correctly?

Comment: Each minion you play on the Homeworld gives you an extra <=2 power minion play that turn, which doesn't have to be on the Homeworld as well. If it is, you get another one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. If it could only be triggered once per turn, it would read:

> After the first time a minion is played here each turn, ...

Comment: That feels so overpowered, but probably I had just luck that the Portal got me a lot of low powered minions on the hand before.

Comment: @Mnementh It's situationally powerful, but a stack of low-powered minions are a tasty target for a few different decks, and can be taken advantage of by opponents in a variety of ways.

Comment: @ikegami You're not wrong that it's incredibly powerful for robots, but it's actually an alien faction base!